# Data subsetting in Stata with integers and strings vs. R

Tags: r, aggregate, stata, ram

I've never used Stata before and have a very scanty knowledge of it. I've been trying to collapse a dataset of bilateral information according to `year`, `country1`, `country2`, and take the means of all other information. In R, I tried running:

```
aggregate(dataset,by=list(dataset$year,dataset$country1,dataset$country2),FUN=mean,na.rm=TRUE)
```

The dataset is too large for my computer's RAM to handle my collapsing in R (another issue I can't solve), and when a colleague attempted to run the code, other data were not shown as means (in some cases, only the data from one row of a particular dyad-year was selected; in others, I'm not even sure what happened). Smaller subsets of the dataset showed correct results.

Because of the issue in R, I want to try doing this in Stata, but whereas I previously attempted using

```
collapse (mean) <every variable I wanted a ``mean'' of, or otherwise wanted to remove from the dataset>, by(year country1 country2)
```

Stata did not know how to handle strings. I have so little understanding of Stata, that I can't figure out how to resolve this issue. Could someone please provide me the code I would need to use the `collapse` command on a large number of variables, many of which are strings (and, in the case of strings, for which I want `NA` returns)?

Comment: Do you have a sample of data that you can share? then you can paste the output of dput(data[sample(1:nrow(data),50)]? I suspect what's going on is that your data has a mix of character and numeric variables and you're aggregating all of them in your call.

Comment: Well, the output is 99 variables. I'll give it a shot.

Comment: This seems like a great use case for SQLite accessed via R, possibly with `dplyr` as a front-end.  Or `data.table` may even work if the data fits into memory but the collapse operation is what's taking up too much space.

Comment: Also, are you sure Stata is considering it a string and not a factor (which it represents as an integer with a variable label)?

Comment: Not sure. Incidentally, infominer, I'm apparently not proficient enough to get that to work with this level of data.

Comment: You say "Stata did not know how to handle strings.". How do you expect Stata to compute the mean of a string variable? You need to decide what you're going to do with string variables before trying the `collapse`. I think this is only natural. For your particular application, what do you expect happens to the string variables after the `collapse`?

Comment: In Stata, `help collapse` reads "_clist_ must refer to numeric variables exclusively.", where _clist_ includes the variables to process.

Answer (score 2):

You can select numeric variables automatically with `ds`. `ds` is an official command. `findname` (*Stata Journal*) is a user-written successor to `ds` with more functionality (fact) and a friendlier syntax (author's opinion, although the same author was the last author of `ds`).

```
. sysuse auto
(1978 Automobile Data)

. ds, has(type numeric)
price         rep78         trunk         length        displacement  foreign
mpg           headroom      weight        turn          gear_ratio

. findname, type(numeric)
price         rep78         trunk         length        displacement  foreign
mpg           headroom      weight        turn          gear_ratio
```

In both cases, you will find that the names of numeric variables are returned in `r(varlist)`:

```
. di "`r(varlist)'"
price mpg rep78 headroom trunk weight length turn displacement gear_ratio foreign
```

so that you feed that to `collapse`

```
. collapse `r(varlist)',  by(year country1 country2)
```

In general, there is no substitute for reading the help and manual entry for `collapse`.

Answer (score 1):

If the string variables you are trying to compute a mean for are numbers treated as strings, e.g. "1", "2", etc., then you can convert the variable to numeric type using `real()`or `destring`. String variables not in this form, e.g. "alligator", "lizard", "snake", etc., for which you want no mean, will be dropped if they are not included in the `collapse`.

Example:

```
clear all
set more off

* some example data
input ///
str4 numstr num str11 reptiles
"234" 234 "alligator"
"2135" 2135 "lizard"
"324" 324 "snake"
end

list

* create numeric variable from string
destring(numstr), gen(num2)

* the collapse
collapse (mean) num num2

list
```